# How to access props data?

Tags: vue.js

I have an PHP var used in a blade template and want to pass it to a vue's method.

I'm still learning so sorry if it seems obvious but I read the docs but found noting useful.

So I have this piece of code in my **HTML**

```
<chat-messages :messages="messages" :surgery_id="{{ $surgery->id }}"></chat-messages>
```

And in my **JS**

```
Vue.component('chat-messages', require('./components/ChatMessages.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#chat',

    methods: {
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get('/messages/').then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },
    }
});
```

And I want to use something like `axios.get('/messages/' + surgery_id).then(...)`

But I can't figure out how to retrieve this `surgery_id` variable

In my **ChatMessages.vue**, I well created the properties

```
<template>
    //Stuff to loop & display
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['messages' , 'surgery_id']
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` as you do normally with the data:

```
axios.get('/messages/' + this.surgery_id).then(...)
```

You can access all the property of data option,props, and methods using `this` as context.

Further, if you want to use ES6, then it's even easier without concatenating them: (using tilde key `)

```
axios.get(`/messages/${this.surgery_id}`).then(...)
```

---

As per your query, you also need to pass props in your instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
  // ...
  propsData:{
    surgery_id: 'your id value'
  }
```

See [my another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680079/pass-props-component-to-root-instance/49011528#49011528) for more help.

Comment: The variable is always `undefined`. Should I declare it somewhere else than in my `<chat-messages :surgery_id="something"` and in `props: ['messages' , 'surgery_id']` ?