# How do I make this component to pass its value into a parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I had 2 components - search filter, and iterator in the same component **App.vue** like that:

#### App.vue

```html
<v-text-field 
  :search="search"
  v-model="search"
  label="type here to filter" 
>
</v-text-field>


<v-data-iterator
  :items="sortedContents"
  :search="search"
  v-model="selected"
>
  ...
</v-data-iterator>

...

data () {
  return {
    search: '',
  {
}
```

But then I moved that search filter into a separate component called `<toolbar>` and it the search filter inside it doesn't work anymore:

#### App.vue

```html
<!-- this component contains the <v-text-field> -->
<toolbar :search="search"></toolbar>


<v-data-iterator
  :items="sortedContents"
  :search="search"
  v-model="selected"
>
  ...
</v-data-iterator>

...

data () {
  return {
    search: '',
  {
}
```

---

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddEjgp?editors=1010

---

### Question:

What should I add into that new `<toolbar>` component in order for it to pass the data typed into that search filter to the **App.vue** parent component?

Comment: You need to pass props, you'll get some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680079/pass-props-component-to-root-instance/49011528#49011528

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I just update the codepen, I added `props: ['search'],`  but it still doesn't work, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting that changed `search` value will be availiable to parent component and this is wrong. According to vue docs:

> [**One-Way Data Flow**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

> All props form a *one-way-down* binding between the
> child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates,
> it will flow down to the child, but **not the other way around**.
>
> In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in
> the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. This
> means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child
> component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

You should handle `change` or `input` (more appropriate to your task) events in toolbar's `v-text-field` (`@input="onInput"`) and emit some event (`this.$emit('filterinput', str)`) to pop data to parent component! And parent should listen (`@filterinput="localSearchUpdate"`) to that event (`filterinput` in codepen) and change (method `localSearchUpdate`) local to him `search` data with received from event string:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJgqqv?editors=1010

Comment: Ah, now I understand it, thank you very much for explaining it!