# Vuejs pass value from instance to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to pass a value from my vue instance to my vue component.

I have following vue component (vuejs dropzonejs component), which das basically a nice Image upload ui.

```
<template>
    <vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone" id="dropzone" :options="dropzoneOptions"></vue-dropzone>
</template>

<script>
import vue2Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone'
import 'vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.css'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            game: {
                title: ''
            },
            dropzoneOptions: {
                url: '/games/upload',
                method: 'post',
                params: {
                    title: this.game.title
                }
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        processFiles () {
            this.$refs.myVueDropzone.processQueue();
        },

        getGameTitle () {
            this.game.title = '',
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I Need to get the game title from my vue instance and pass it to my vue component so that I can do some work there with that title.

My vue instance Looks like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('vue-dropzone', require('./components/ImageDropzoneComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        loading: false,
        title: '',
    },

    methods: {
        createGame (e) {
            this.uploadImage();
            axios.post('/games',  {
                title: this.title,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },

        uploadImage () {
            this.$refs.myVueDropzone.processFiles()
        },

        getGameTitle () {
            return this.title;
        }

    }
});
```

The tag:

```
<vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone"></vue-dropzone>
```

Comment: This might be a interest for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680079/pass-props-component-to-root-instance

Comment: Show the `#app`'s template.

Comment: @acdcjunior the apps template?

Comment: so you're not using vuex?

Comment: @AyushGupta nope still beginning to learn vue

Comment: where do you get the title from? it is static?

Comment: I dont get any title in my component yet in my instance I get it from an Input text

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Comment: The main template, the one you are adding your custom element in.

Comment: @acdcjunior I am using this https://rowanwins.github.io that includes that

Comment: I mean, you say *I have following vue component* and then show a custom component (that imports `vue-dropzone` in its template). What I'm asking is for you to show the template that imports such custom component of yours.