# Passing props to root instances in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

**The problem**

I am trying to pass a prop to my root constructor. I understand that `propsData` [is the way to go](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-props-to-root-instances-in-2-0/244/2):

```
var appComponent = Vue.component('app', require('./components/app/app.vue.html'));
new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes }),
    propsData: { test: 'hi!' },
    components: { appComponent },
    render: h => h('app')
});
```

This is the `AppComponent` that receives the prop:

```
export default class AppComponent extends Vue {

    @Prop()
    test: string;

    mounted() {
        console.log('test = ' + this.test);
        // result: test = undefined
        // expected: test = 'hi!'
    }
}
```

---

**Things I have tried**

The only way to make it work *in development* (not in production) was:

```
test: string;

beforeCreate() {
    this.test = this.$root.test;
}
```

It work on development (windows), but in deployment (linux) I got this typescript error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ClientApp/components/app/app.ts:14:34
    TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46680079/831138) is another post talking about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass `props` in the [`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) object which is the 2nd argument the `createElement` alias `h` function takes in the `render` option

```
render: h => h('app', { props: { test: 'hi!' }})
```

Comment: Purely awesome... A few alternatives: https://filosophy.org/code/passing-props-to-a-root-vue-component-from-its-surrounding-html || https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/props-data.html || https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/components-with-props.html